# Contract_ABI returned from API call has JSON interface error

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js

I am trying to setup a smart contract from getting the contract ABI from BSCSCAN testnet API. I have successfully managed to get the contract ABI of USDT (https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x337610d27c682e347c9cd60bd4b3b107c9d34ddd) from the TESTNET API however when I try to setup the contract I am getting this error:

```
Error: You must provide the json interface of the contract when instantiating a contract object.
    at Contract (C:\Users\User\Documents\Coding Projects\trading-bot - modified\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\src\index.js:70:15)
    at new Contract (C:\Users\User\Documents\Coding Projects\trading-bot - modified\node_modules\web3-eth\src\index.js:149:22)
```

Here is my async functions that run in a main() function to get the ABI

```
// Funciton to get the token ABI that uses the BSCSCAN API to get the token you want (IN THIS CASE USDT)
async function getTokenWanted(){
let tokenAddress = '0x337610d27c682e347c9cd60bd4b3b107c9d34ddd';
let tokenWantedAPI = "https://api-testnet.bscscan.com/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address="+tokenAddress+"&apikey=" +process.env.BSCSCAN_API;

        try {
          const res = await fetch(tokenWantedAPI);
          const headerDate = res.headers && res.headers.get('date') ? res.headers.get('date') : 'no response date';
          console.log('Status Code:', res.status);
          console.log('Date in Response header:', headerDate);
          let users = await res.json();
          contractABI =users.result;

          return contractABI
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err.message); //can be console.error
        }
}

// Function to setup the token contract 
async function setupTokenWantedContract(){
  let contract_ABI = await getTokenWanted();
  console.log(contract_ABI);
  let token_Address ='0x337610d27c682e347c9cd60bd4b3b107c9d34ddd';
  const tokenContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contract_ABI, token_Address);
  
  return tokenContract;
}
```

These functions run in a main function like this:

```
async function main(){

let tokenWantedContract = awaitsetupTokenWantedContract()

}
```

The gathered ABI contract when logged to the console is this **(this is exactly the same as when you go to the contract ABI in bscscan and just copy and paste it to the code, however I would want to do this dynamically hence me using the API):**

```
[{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"_decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"_name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"_symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"subtractedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"decreaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getOwner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"addedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]
```

Here are what I tried so far:

- Wrapping the result of the api into a JSON.Parse(), but the error is the same if it is wrapped in JSON.Parse() or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I somehow got it to work when I used JSON.Parse on this codeblock:

```
// Funciton to get the token ABI that uses the BSCSCAN API to get the token you want (IN THIS CASE USDT)
async function getTokenWanted(){
let tokenAddress = '0x337610d27c682e347c9cd60bd4b3b107c9d34ddd';
let tokenWantedAPI = "https://api-testnet.bscscan.com/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address="+tokenAddress+"&apikey=" +process.env.BSCSCAN_API;

        try {
          const res = await fetch(tokenWantedAPI);
          const headerDate = res.headers && res.headers.get('date') ? res.headers.get('date') : 'no response date';
          console.log('Status Code:', res.status);
          console.log('Date in Response header:', headerDate);
          let users = await res.json();
          contractABI =JSON.parse(users.result);

          return contractABI
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err.message); //can be console.error
        }
}
```

Weird, must be something wrong when I first tried JSON.Parse().